# parse domains from html page using perl

Tags: html, perl, parsing, url, dns

i have an html page that contain urls like :

```
<h3><a href="http://site.com/path/index.php" h="blablabla">
<h3><a href="https://www.site.org/index.php?option=com_content" h="vlavlavla">
```

i want to extract :

```
site.com/path
www.site.org
```

between `<h3><a href="` & `/index.php` .

i've tried this code :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (MYFILE, 'MyFileName.txt');
while (<MYFILE>) 
{
  my $values1 = split('http://', $_); #VALUE WILL BE: www.site.org/path/index2.php
  my @values2 = split('index.php', $values1); #VALUE WILL BE: www.site.org/path/ ?option=com_content

    print $values2[0]; # here it must print www.site.org/path/ but it don't
    print "\n";
}
close (MYFILE);
```

but this give an output :

```
2
1
2
2
1
1
```

and it don't parse https websites.
hope you've understand , regards.

Comment: You are splitting on `$_` in the line `my $values1 = ...` but this variable has no defined value unless you have passed something on the command line.  You should split on something you can positively identify to know what the result means.

Comment: `$_` is set by the line `while (<MYFILE>)` which is a common Perl idiom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing wrong with your code is that when you call `split` in scalar context as in your line:

```
my $values1 = split('http://', $_);
```

It returns the size of the list created by the `split`.  See [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

But I don't think `split` is appropriate for this task anyway.  If you know that the value you are looking for will always lie between 'http[s]://' and '/index.php' you just need a regex substitution in your loop (you should also be more careful opening your file...):

```
open(my $myfile_fh, '<', 'MyFileName.txt') or die "Couldn't open $!";
while(<$myfile_fh>) {
    s{.*http[s]?://(.*)/index\.php.*}{$1} && print;
}

close($myfile_fh);
```

It's likely you will need a more general regex than that, but I think this would work based on your description of the problem.

Comment: hi dms , but i can't save output into a file . ive tried :

    open(my $sort, 'tt8-4.txt') or die "Couldn't open $!";
    while(<$sort>) {
    (s{.*http[s]?://(.*)/index\.php.*}{$1});
    open (save,"1.txt") or die "$!" ;
    print save "$1\n";
    close (save);
       }
    close($sort);

but it don't work

Comment: When you opened `save` like that you opened it for reading.  To open it for writing you need to use a '>' or for appending (which is what you want to do), use a '>>'.  Like this: `open ($save, '>>', '1.txt')`.  You should also move the `open` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This feels to me like a job for modules

- [HTML::LinkExtor](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.71/lib/HTML/LinkExtor.pm)
- [URI](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI-1.60/URI.pm)

Generally using regexps to parse HTML is risky.

Answer (score 0):

[dms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2530215/dms) explained in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18295867/1521179) why using `split` isn't the best solution here:

- It returns the number of items in scalar context
- A normal regex is better suited for this task.

However, I do not think that line-based processing of the input is valid for HTML, or that using a substitution makes sense (it does not, especially when the pattern looks like `.*Pattern.*`).

Given an URL, we can extract the required information like

```
if ($url =~ m{^https?://(.+?)/index\.php}s) {  # domain+path now in $1
  say $1;
}
```

But how do we extract the URLs? I'd recommend the wonderful Mojolicious suite.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use File::Slurp 'slurp';  # makes it easy to read files.
use Mojo;

my $html_file = shift @ARGV;  # take file name from command line

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(scalar slurp $html_file);

for my $link ($dom->find('a[href]')->each) {
  say $1 if $link->attr('href') =~ m{^https?://(.+?)/index\.php}s;
}
```

The `find` method can take CSS selectors (here: all `a` elements that have an `href` attribute). The `each` flattens the result set into a list which we can loop over.

As I print to STDOUT, we can use shell redirection to put the output into a wanted file, e.g.

```
$ perl the-script.pl html-with-links.html >only-links.txt
```

The whole script as a one-liner:

```
$ perl -Mojo -E'$_->attr("href") =~ m{^https?://(.+?)/index\.php}s and say $1 for x(b("test.html")->slurp)->find("a[href]")->each'
```